# Failed to load ApplicationContext: Used @TestConfiguration in another test class having bean as "headerProcessor"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have one test class with @TestConfiguation and inside that a bean is returned as "headerProcessor".
Now that same bean I am importing and @autowiring in the class. Now if I run this class it is working fine. I am running the test class as Spring runner
But if I run another test class getting error like "Failed to load ApplicationContext" caused by UnsatisfiedDependencyException for bean "headerProcessor".

Sorry I cannot paste the codes its restricted from the company.